# compare list 1 with list 2 and get the corresponding list 3 value using excel?

Tags: excel

How can I compare list 1 with list 2 and get the corresponding list 3 value using Excel?

Example:
    Input data is as below

```
Column A  Column B  Column C
1         5         same
2         4         different
3         3         same
4         6         no match
5         7         no match
```

I want to compare column A data with column B; if it matches get the corresponding column C value and put it in column D, like this:

```
Column A  Column D
1         no match
2         no match
3         same
4         different
5         same
```

Answer (score 1):

You want this formula in Column D

```
=IF(A2=B2,C2,"")
```

And repeat it down column D. Or ==>

```
=IF(A2=B2,"match","no match")
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to try and find the value from column A in column B, and return the value in column C. That can be done with a `VLOOKUP`; put this formula in cell D1 and copy down:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, $B$1:$C$5, 2, False)
```

`A1` is the thing you're looking up.
`$B$1:$C$5` is the table containing the lookup table, in this case

```
5         same
4         different
3         same
6         no match
7         no match
```

`2` means get the answer from the second column (column C)
`False` means only allow exact matches.

We need to get it to say "no match" if that didn't work:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, $B$1:$C$5, 2, False), "no match")
```

As a side note, the content of column C is confusingly chosen, but the formula I've given here gives the result you asked for.